# FastAPI Application with Uvicorn Runs Differently in Docker: Background Tasks Wait to Complete Before Responding

Tags: python-3.x, docker, fastapi

I have developed a FastAPI application that processes video uploads asynchronously. The application works as expected on my local macOS environment: it immediately responds to requests, allowing the video processing to occur in the background. However, when I run the same application in a Docker container, the behavior changes—now, the API waits for the background video processing task to complete before sending a response, which is not the desired behavior.

Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks, UploadFile, File
import uvicorn
from some_module import process_video

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_video(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, video: UploadFile = File(...)):
    background_tasks.add_task(process_video, video.file)
    return {"message": "Processing started"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)

Comment: While FastAPI provides a way to execute background tasks (inherited directly from Starlette), I would still suggest setting up a Celery worker with a tasks queue. [Their own docs recommend it](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#caveat). Since you are already using Docker, it can be very easy to setup a Celery container, plus a Redis/RabbitMQ one. If you would like to keep using the FastAPI-only approach, you should share your `process_video` function as well as your `Dockerfile`